# Allowing telegram through firewall: how to find which ports have to be opened?

Tags: networking, firewall

I'm behind firewall, and I lack information how to find out, which IP/port has to be opened for certain application. In my current case, it is telegram.

I did not find any document "allow these IPs/ports". I found telegram-related IP ranges, but when I used `sudo tcpdump -i <iface> -nn -s 0 -v > /tmp/tcpDump` and generate some outgoing traffic, I'm not able to find any of these IPs. And that's pretty much where my "knowledge" ends.

How can I find, what has to be configured on firewall? (sure, I'd like to hear telegram-related answer, but I'm more after how is this resolved generally).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not very familiar with telegram so this is from the perspective of an administrator doing general troubleshooting for ports.

**Most applications usually have documentations what needs to be enabled to allow the application to work**. You can usually find a list ports, IPs, FQDN by simply googling, "what ports does  use". In your specific example the google results shows the following: https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks

> A webhook needs an open port on your server. We currently support the following ports: 443, 80, 88 and 8443. Other ports are not supported and will not work. Make sure your bot is running on one of those supported ports, and that the bot is reachable via its public address.
>
> By default that means we’re knocking at your door on port 443

Once you get this port information you usually do a test to see if my device can even reach said listener. My preferred method and I truly believe is one of the easiest way is to try and telnet to the host on that port. It doesn't matter if they have a telnet server setup or not, you can verify that the destination is valid. So on a window server I'd fire up the command prompt and try **telnet 149.154.167.197 443**. In all linux distribution you can use the identical command **telnet 149.154.167.197 443**. If you get a response you can narrow it down that the issue is somewhere on the source or that is not the port you need.

**If you are unable to find any documentation or it doesn't appear to be working you can search your active connections**. On windows you can do this by firing up the application and then opening up the command prompt and running the command **netstat -a -b** . Netstat is a command that displays information about TCP connections on your device. On most linux distribution you can use the much more robust **nstat -a** from iproute2.

This should solve your issue with finding ports almost every single time. If it does not **your last major tool is to download a packet analyzer tool such as ngrep or wireshark and manually analyze traffic from your device**. If you know the source/destination you can usually find it pretty quick.

A final note is that before anything if it is going out on the internet. There is a very large chance it will be using port 80 (http) or 443 (https) and should probably be the first guess unless it is using a distinct protocol.

Comment: I found webpage you referenced. Also one can get IP ranges of telegram by "telegram ip". Next I have 2 envs. On one app works, on other it does not. So I did tcpdump on env which works to find out, what IP from given list is being contacted, and from that confirm used ports. The problem is, that NO ip from your is used, no ip from https://ipinfo.io/AS62041 is used. I used tcpdump which should be equivallent to wireshark. I also tried ntopng, but I did not have any luck using that (probably outdated app version on ubuntu). I did not scan active connections, as I expect shortlived calls.

Comment: ... but messages reached telegram endpoint. So a) incorrect tcpdump invocation b) incorrect IPs c) no other explanation comes to my mind.

Comment: That is strange. Particularly that you cannot find the IP being used. Is anything different about the two environment as far as you know? Such as different firewalls, different routes, or anything different within telegram itself. If you are unable to find anything within the network it might be an issue within the application itself. Hopefully someone more familiar with telegram can help you out.

Comment: So google for telegram IP shows: `149.154.160.0/22, 149.154.164.0/22, 91.108.4.0/22, 91.108.56.0/22, 91.108.8.0/22, 95.161.64.0/20`. Your page says for example: `If you want to limit access to Telegram only, please allow traffic from 149.154.167.197-233`. Or `Accepts incoming POSTs from subnets 149.154.160.0/20 and 91.108.4.0/22 on port 443, 80, 88, or 8443.` So I fired third pc, same tcp dump, verified that it dump curl calls, and then tried telegram again. No hit for any IP. So I compared both dump, and `dig` all IPs ...

Comment: ... So contacted IP from telegram app is: "149.154.167.92", which belongs to telegram, but is not specified in any range, if I'm looking correctly. Now: a) this is hardly the correct procedure how to find what should be opened b)considering the number of telegram IPs, this IP can change at any time. So this finding is kinda useless.

Comment: however it is. I'm not looking correctly, as I'm retarted and cannot read ipv4 suffixes. It's covered by 149.154.164.0/22. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: That documentation is about bots receiving connections from Telegram, not normal clients trying to contact Telegram